# Require duplicates to be imported in Shotwell

Tags: shotwell

I have some drawings that I have imported and tagged by date. Now I want to take some of them that I have organized on my disk and put give them a new tag. Shotwell thinks they are duplicates and won't import them. Is there a way to require Shotwell to import these duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

Right now you'd have to do this at compile time by configuring with:

```
./configure --define=NO_DUPE_DETECTION
```

You should be able to build following these instructions: http://www.yorba.org/projects/shotwell/install/.

I wouldn't suspect this is a commonly used code path, so some things might not work exactly how you might expect. Please file a bug report on either pantheon photos (elementary os) or shotwell on the gnome website if this doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I add a comment or a tag to the images already present in Shotwell. If your write the metadata to the file (option in preferences) the file changes and from then on Shotwell will import the same pictures (without the comment or tag).

Answer (score 0):

the only solution for me
It was change the md5 PhotoTable field of table
see 
[I need to import pictures twice in Shotwell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/647644/i-need-to-import-pictures-twice-in-shotwell/650328#650328)

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Shotwell preferences and activate the option to write metadata tags to image files, they will not be reported as duplicated when you re-import them.