# I need to import pictures twice in Shotwell

Tags: shotwell, photo-management

I am importing photos in Shotwell folder by folder, adding tags and titles. All was going well but suddenly after selecting a folder using import in file, there is a box asking if I want to cancel, copy photos or import in place.

I choose import and then get another box saying:

> 1 non-image file skipped

and then there is no copying and I need to go to file again and redo the process, now it will copy and import.

How can I get rid of this bug? I tried restarting but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

Shotwell used to compare md5; see [How does Shotwell detect duplicates?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509133/how-does-shotwell-detect-duplicates).

I could not find how to set variable `NO_DUPE_DETECTION`. The only solution for me was to change the md5 PhotoTable field of the table using

```
sqlite3 ~/.local/share/shotwell/data/photo.db  "update phototable set md5=''"
```

You can add a function to `.bashrc`

```
rmmd5 ()
{
sqlite3 ~/.local/share/shotwell/data/photo.db  "update phototable set md5=''"
}
```

and run it every time you import.

Comment: Thanks. For some bug, shotwell sometimes think some pics are dupes when..they aren't, this fixes it. Now I need to clear the memory card between imports, but I usually do that.