# Disabling shotwell duplicate detection

Tags: shotwell, photo-management

I'm new to Ubuntu. Afaik shotwell is the best option to view photos in recursive/multiple folders. I want to see them even if they are duplicated, but I don't know how to disable the duplicate detection feature in shotwell.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240642/require-duplicates-to-be-imported-in-shotwell) and [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/647644/i-need-to-import-pictures-twice-in-shotwell/650328#650328) are similar but they don't have a proper answer and they are both outdated.

Second question: is there any software that can list all images in given folders other than shotwell?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second question, there are many other options, such as `gthumb`, `feh` (try `feh -ZXrF ./`), `digikam`.

I suppose that you don't need to be taught how to install software.

For your first question, if there is no mention of any such option, then maybe you'll have to modify the source code and recompile. I know that this is a task that is out of reach for most.